# What means this Vue devtools version hint?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-devtools

My Vue devtools show this version hint:

[image]

I don't understand from where the version number 3.2.28 is coming though or to what exactly it refers to - my vue version is 3.2.25.

Comment: Are you using a CDN runtime or have you no package-lock.json and the dependencies setup so they always take the latest patch versions when using npm install?

Comment: @Thomas I have a package-lock.json and use the npm version, not from CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see much more than what you provided in the image, but I think a reasonable guess is that you are using something like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.25"
  },
```

If that's the case, the install script will get the latest patch version, which would be `3.2.28` at the time of install, and `3.2.29` at the time of screenshot. This will also update the npm (or yarn) package which will make it re-install `3.2.28` even when `3.2.29`

if you want to lock it, remove the `^` character, if you want to understand better why and how this is happening look into the [Using semantic versioning to specify update types your package can accept](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#using-semantic-versioning-to-specify-update-types-your-package-can-accept) documentation

Comment: thank you for your explanation, your guess was indeed correct!